# Stress Bulbs for strip "continuous" footings

Tags: civil-engineering, geotechnical-engineering, foundations

How can I plot such a graph with Excel or Matlab by a uniform load q, and how can I see where the stress becomes 0.1q?

The loaded area and the equation is on the picture shown below, equation is highlighted in yellow

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The plotting in Matlab can certainly be done with a contour plot once you include the equations in your question.

Comment: @MuradNazari This is similar to some instantly recognizable geotech charts that can be found in any textbook. The two methods I am aware of to create these charts use either the Bousinesq equations ([example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8182793/Stackoverflow/Bousinesq%20eq%20-%20square%20and%20strip%20footings.png)) or the Westergaard equations ([example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8182793/Stackoverflow/Westergaard%20eq%20-%20square%20and%20strip%20footings.png)). However, your chart does not match either of those charts. I need to know what method it is using.

Comment: @GlenH7 Ah ha! I found what method is being used here: it's Bousinesq for the stress increase under a *flexible* strip loaded footing (the method can be found in Das, Principles of Geotechnical Engineering). Since it is now obvious what method is being used I think you can reopen the question. Probably needs to be edited though. I can do that but not today.

Comment: @GlenH7 Thanks for mentioning Boussinesq (is it one or two s?). I use it very often in the context of contact pressures and deflections.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula to calculate it based on the x, horizontal distance and z vertical distance.
Simply put z=0 and increment it say by 0.1 in excel while x starts from B/2.
[image]

Formula
[image]

sample calculations
[image]

[image]